# implicit function theorem and one to one function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Apply the IFT to show that no $C^1$ function $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ can be one to one near any points of its domain.

So I know that the theorem says that if we have a point $(a,b)$ such that $F(a,b)=0$ and gradient $F(a,b)$ not zero then there is a neighborhood of $(a,b)$ such that we can find a $C^1$ function $y=f(x)$ and I know that to prove a function is one to one we can show that if $f(x,y)=f(a,b)$ then $x=a$ and $y=b$ but I don't see how to link the two.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the differential of $F$ at $x$, $$d_xF:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$$ Note that $d_xF$ has rank $0$ or $1$. Those $x$ for which $d_xF$ has rank $0$ form a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, since $d_xF=0$ if and only if the partials of $F$ vanish at $x$ and these partials are continuous. So, $d_xF$ has rank $1$ on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This should allow you to apply the Implicit Function Theorem to obtain your result.